# Use jstransform with webpack and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm used to write my React's JSX files using ES6 syntax provided by [jstransform](https://github.com/facebook/jstransform). I love it.

It get compiled for the client with webpack + [jsx-loader](https://github.com/petehunt/jsx-loader) – with the `?harmony` switch. 
On node, I use [node-jsx](https://github.com/petehunt/node-jsx) module to require directly .jsx files.

Yet my "normal" js scripts are still using the "old" ES5 syntax. 
How can i use jstransform there, i.e. use ES6 syntax on both node.js and browser?

- on node: is the --harmony switch working as jstransform or should i use a plugin similar to node-jsx?
- on webpack: how to compile using jstransform? I tried with [jstransform-loader](https://github.com/conradz/jstransform-loader) but it can't make it working.

Comment: Re: node --harmony vs jsx — a rough ES6 support in both is at http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I found there that 6to5 makes exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using [6to5](https://6to5.org). It works with React and has a [webpack loader](https://github.com/6to5/6to5-loader) as well!

For node there's also a require hook:

```
require("6to5/register");
```